# Bootstrap modal window instead of jQuery modal window

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new in web. I wrote this jQuery modal window:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" class="modal-body" style="display:none;">
  <p>@Html.TextArea("commentForDecline")</p>
  <button title="Ok" class="btn btn-primary ok-request">Ok</button>
</div>
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```
function declineButtonClick(th) {    
  tempId = $(th).attr('data-id');
  $('#dialog').attr('data-id', tempId);
  $("#dialog").dialog();
}

$('button.ok-request').click(function () {
  var tempId = $('#dialog').attr('data-id');
  var message = $('textarea#commentForDecline').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/TableRequest/DeclineRequest",
    data: { 'message': message, 'id': tempId },
      success: function (msg) {
    }
  });
  $("#dialog").dialog('close');
  $('button[data-id="' + tempId + '"]')
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find('div.True')
    .attr('class', "False");

  $('button[data-id="' + tempId + '"]')
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find('img.decline-img')
    .show();

  $('button[data-id="' + tempId + '"]')
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find('img.accept-img')
    .hide();

  $('button[data-id="' + tempId + '"]')
    .parent()
    .find('button.decline-button')
    .hide();

  $('button[data-id="' + tempId + '"]')
    .parent()
    .find('button.accept-button')
    .show();

  $('textarea#commentForDecline').val('');
});
```

I need to put bootstrap classic modal window instead of my jQuery modal window. So I added bootstrap class, but nothing changed. I know that it should be simple but can't do it. Can anyone help me? I will be very grateful.

Comment: did you link `bootstrap` files??

Comment: You will need to use bootstrap js to manage modal...the 2 scripts aren't interchangeable. Also need to use bootstrap markup

Comment: 1) Of course I did it. 2) Can you provide any example?

Comment: See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E032 regarding the required HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your have included the the bootstrap js in your View (bootstrap.js)

If you are opening the modal via javascript, use correct syntax:

```
$("#dialog").modal(//options);

// within the on-click function
$("#dialog").modal('show');
```

If you are opening it via modal markup, use correct syntax:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog">Click Me</button>

<div id="dialog" class="modal" role="modal" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Basic Dialog</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>@Html.TextArea("commentForDecline")</p>
        <button title="Ok" class="btn btn-primary ok-request">Ok</button>
      </div> // end of body
    </div> // end of modal content
  </div> // end of modal dialog
</div> // end of modal div
```

Regardless of which method you choose to open your modal, you definitely need to declare the bootstrap.js script as well as the style sheet.